# Get only a part of a directory name. Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I only wanted to get the part of this path

path = `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\unpack\folder1`

should be

result = `unpack\folder1`

programatically

[In short, I only wanted to get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Gfv.png)
Please help me using vb.net codes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\unpack\folder1")
Dim dirAndParent = $"{dir.Parent}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{dir.Name}"
```

If you use older version of Visual Basic:

```
Dim dirAndParent = dir.Parent & Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & dir.Name
```

**Edit**: Probably the best approach i first have forgotten is to use `IO.Path.Combine`:

```
Dim dirAndParent = Path.Combine(parentDir.Name, dir.Name)
```

Comment: I don't get this code.
Dim dirAndParent = $"{dir.Parent}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{dir.Name}"

Comment: @alexiefication: what visual-studio version do you use? That's called string interpolation and is another (nicer) version of `String.Format`. You need at least visual-studio 2015(visual-basic .NET 14).

Comment: @alexiefication `$"{dir.Parent.Name}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{dir.Name}"` is equal to `String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", dir.Parent.Name, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, dir.Name)`, which is also equal to `dir.Parent.Name & Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & dir.Name`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: yes, or simple concatenation with `&` which is readable too because there is nothing between them

Comment: I only got Visual Studio 2008 and I visual-basic .NET 9.0

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thank you. this code works for me
String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", dir.Parent.Name, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, dir.Name)

Comment: @alexiefication: note that you should use `Path.Combine(parentDir.Name, dir.Name)`. It's the easiest approach